# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #4

Tags: visual, rebus

Moving along... same parameters as the previous puzzles.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is

> Arch Hammer, also from *The Four of Us Are Dying*

Comment: Yes! Maybe this was too easy.